# Template engine?

Tags: templating

Is there a simple software out there that will take a template,
some properties in a text file

and will transplant the properties in a template?

for example : template file:

> Dear STUDENT_NAME parents, On day TODAY_DATE ,
> your child was absent
> from school.
> your teacher TEACHER_NAME

and property file:

- STUDENT_NAME=Jonathan
- TODAY_DATE=12/06/2022
- TEACHER_NAME=Rachel

the software will take both and produce a  text file:

> Dear Jonathan parents, On day 12/06/2022 ,
> your child was absent
> from school.
> your teacher Rachel

Comment: I know i can write the same software in velocity or thymeleaf in few hours :) but a Windows UI is more complex.

Comment: I should think that most word processors are capable of this through their "mail merge" capability.